# Family of operators is bounded pointwise

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Let $c_{00}=\{f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}\colon\exists N\in\mathbb{N}~~\text{with}~~ f(n)=0~~\text{for all}~~ n>N\}$ with $\|f\|_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(n)|$. For every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ let $T\colon c_{00}\to c_{00}$,
>
> $T_ke_n=\begin{cases} ne_n, \text{if}~~n\leq k\\ 0,\text{if}~~n>k\end{cases}$
>
> Show, that the family of operators $\{T_k\colon k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded pointwise, but not bounded uniformly.

I have to show, that for every $f\in c_{00}$ exists a constant $c_f>0$ such that $\|T_kf\|_1\leq c_f$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ but it does not exists an upper bound for $\{\|T_k\|_{op}\colon k\in\mathbb{N}\}$

I am stuck here. Can you help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(n) = 0 $ for $n>N$, then $T_k(f) = T_N(f)$ for $k\geq N$, so $\{T_k f\}_k$ is bounded for any $f\in c_{00}$.

On the other hand, if you consider the sequence of **unitary** vectors ${e_j}\in c_{0,0}$ where $(e_j)_n = \delta_{j n}$, you have that 
$$\sup_k ||T_k|| = \sup_k \sup_{||f||_{c_{00}}=1} ||T_kf|| \geq \sup_k ||T_k e_k|| = \sup_k k = +\infty$$

Comment: Thats all?? Wow. But does this statement not contradict Banach-Steinhaus?

Comment: No, since $c_{00}$ is not a Banach. Indeed $\{f_n\}_n$ where $f_n(k) = \frac 1 {k^2}$ for $k\leq n$,  $0$ otherwise is Cauchy but it do not converge in $c_{00}$ (it would have infinite non-zero components).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much.